# How do you determine if an "Open" windows explorer window is open in Python?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

In Python I'm using Selenium Chromedriver (both of which I'm fairly new to) to learn how to do some very basic automation. The test that I'm doing at the moment is to determine that the user would be able to open a file using Ctrl/Cmd + O to open the file browser. This part works like a charm. However, in order to determine whether the test passes or fails I need the program to know that the file explorer opens. Does anyone know of a good way to do this? Thank you!

All I have for the current test at the moment is:

```
def test_open_file(self):
   ActionChains(self.driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys("o").perform()
```

Comment: Command/Control-O is a browser feature; it’s not (and shouldn’t be) a feature of your web application. Why would you want to test it?

Comment: I'm doing this as part of a regression test for a web application that allows you to open and edit PDFs, but I want a way for the program to determine whether the file browser does actually open. Otherwise (and I keep getting this happen to me) the test may pass without anything _actually_ happening.

Comment: What were the causes of the regressions?

Comment: By the way, it is an Electron app... The test is just to make sure that when a new feature is added that it hasn't broken anything else. But these can get tedious so it would be nice to automate them.

Comment: How does that integration look? Does Electron provide a JavaScript API with which you declare a callback for opening a file?

Comment: Yes, apparently. In Electron there is a thing called "showOpenDialog" which is being used, and then after the file is selected there is a bit of code that gets called.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium doesn’t have access to any of the browser chrome and thus cannot tell you whether the file explorer is open or not. (Selenium uses the WebDriver specification which only deals with the content of web pages.)

---

While you might be able to figure something out using an OS-specific tool, I would actually recommend that you not test the presence of the actual file explorer.

One, assuming you’re testing a web application, the file explorer itself lives outside of the scope of your application, and thus there’s little value in testing that far. You really only need to test up to the boundary between your application and the browser, i.e., the JavaScript API provided by the browser that triggers the opening of the file explorer—in this case, a keyboard shortcut.

Two, Selenium is a fairly expensive tool, not just because it runs an entire browser but because it inevitably requires integrating the majority of your system. For such a granular detail of your application, this could be more cheaply tested with, say, a JavaScript unit test.